# Where is Database.query() spending (so much) CPU time?

Tags: soql, performance, database, cpu

My assumption was that only Apex Code is using CPU time. But the what I measure for code that is run by Salesforce's own Backend code speak a different language.

```
List<SObject> result = Database.query(soql);
```

When I run the same SQOL query twice, with only 1 field and the next time with 150 fields I see a big increase in CPU time:

1. 1 Field  --> CPU  61 ms
2. 150 Fields --> CPU 300 ms

Comment: Some query constructions require post-database, in-memory filtering to provide the correct results. That said, you said it was only a number of fields change... hmm...

Comment: If you use the query plan tool, does this point to any problem aspects to the query itself (regardless of fields being returned)? I'm wondering if there's some inefficient way of handling the in-memory results that are to be filtered...

Comment: The call goes through SF platform, it's not a direct call to the database. SF platform processes the raw database response to deliver the (instance of the) object to your Apex code. Extracting, formatting the records and transforming them to Apex objects requires CPU. More fields -> more CPU.

Comment: I also presume the types of the fields you're getting returned should be considered - long text area, rich text, etc.